# QuickCheck NonEmpty String - listOf

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

i am learning quickcheck(and haskell too), i have de bellow code:

```
newtype Urls = FN { unFN :: String } deriving Show

instance Arbitrary Urls where
arbitrary = do protocol <- elements ["http://"]
             name <-  listOf $ elements ['a'..'z']
             domain <- elements [".com",".com.br",".net"]
             return (FN (protocol ++ name ++ domain))
```

My question is about how i can make listOf never return empty(NonEmpty), because now for some data generated I receive string like {unFN = "http://.net"}, simplifying i want that name  never be empty

Answer (score 5):

Use `listOf1` instead of `listOf`.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, but this is not a great name for a function I guess :D

Comment: The `1` suffix for non-empty is used in many places, e.g. `foldl1` and `many1`.

Comment: True, but is there any particular reason to use 1 ?